# How to bend into a circle a series of columns rotated at 45 degrees

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to create a frame of poles for a circular body and cannot figure out how to use Simple Deform to bend them into a 360 body. My guess is that my problem lies with where/how I have my vertices but I don't know how better to have them so that, when I put the modifier on, it bends how I want.

[image: Closeup of the Xray]

I created one column, rotated to 45, Arrayed it out 10+ times, applied, tried the Simple Deform. I tried joining the pieces so it's deforming a "single" object. Anyway, I'm stumped after trying a variety of things. This image represents the other side as well. In a last ditch attempt, I tried Joining both thinking that that would create oppositional forces on the bend.

The end product should be a straight wall of lattice pipes in a circle as if it, itself, is a column.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your difficulty is in finding the correct axis and origin point for the bend deformation.
If that's the case, I would create an empty and use it as the origin of the simple deform modifier:
[image]
Then you can just move and rotate the empty until you find the correct position for the deformation you want.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you, Alexandre.